# Django submitting two forms

Tags: python, django, forms

I have question about forms in django. I have two forms for submit. The logic is:

> 1. If in form1 OIB don't existi in database insert it, and insert form2.
> 2. If in form1 OIB exists in database pass, and insert second form(form2), but ask database for id related on OIB from form1.

Below is example of my views.py

## views.py

```
@login_required
```

@csrf_protect
def NewOutgoingInvoice(request):
    template = "novi_izlazni_racun.html"
    user_pk = request.user.id
    org_name = OrganizationInfo.objects.filter(id=user_pk).values('name')[0]
    org_id = request.user.organization_id

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form1 = InsertNewCustomer(request.POST)
    form2 = Outdrew(request.POST, request.user)

    if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid():
        # First form
        a_1, created = OrganizationInfo.objects.get_or_create(**form1.cleaned_data)

        if a_1:
            # Seconf Form
            a_1.save()
            b = form2.save(commit=False)
            b.user_id = request.user
            b.organization_id = org_id
            b.customer_id = a_1
            b.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/novi_izlazni_racuni/')

        if created:
            # Seconf Form
            b = form2.save(commit=False)
            b.user_id = request.user
            b.organization_id = org_id
            b.customer_id = OrganizationInfo.objects.get(oib=form1.cleaned_data['oib'])
            b.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/novi_izlazni_racuni/')
else:
    form1 = InsertNewCustomer()
    form2 = Outdrew()

variables = RequestContext(request, dict(name=org_name, form1=form1, form2=form2))

return render_to_response(template, variables)
```

This view works only if in form1 is new oib and works ok, both forms insert into database, but if OIB already exists forms won't submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `if` will always be executed according to [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create). So the `if` is not necessary.

When form1 OIB exists, your `elif` will not be executed as you wished.

Comment: @cark_kralj looks like you did not use `a` created in `a = form1.save(commit=False)`? Then what does this mean?

Comment: i have removed `a = form1.save(commit=False)`. And updated code.

Comment: @cark_kralj I also modified my answer.